# Equivalent class in JDK9+ for java.util.SubList class in JDK8 or below

Tags: java

If we use JDK8 or below, there is a class called `java.uti.SubList` defined in rt.jar.

The following code works fine in JDK8 or below:

```
Class c = Class.forName("java.util.SubList");
```

Now that I have migrated to JDK9 and higher versions, I am unable to execute the same code.  Its throwing `ClassNotFoundException`.  Anyone aware of the fix for this?  I tried adding java.se module but of no use.

I tried adding various modules of JDK9 but invain.

```
Class c = Class.forName("java.util.SubList");
```

I want that code to run successfully in JDK9+.

## The reason for asking this question is:

The reason I have asked this question is, I am using kryo-serializers library (https://github.com/magro/kryo-serializers) in my java project.

Those guys have used this "java.util.SubList" class. https://github.com/magro/kryo-serializers/blob/master/src/main/java/de/javakaffee/kryoserializers/SubListSerializers.java#L267 This project is breaking in JDK9. I have asked them to look into it but no response. https://github.com/magro/kryo-serializers/issues/112

## I wanted to clone the project and fix the issue myself by finding equivalent of java.util.SubList in JDK9. Thats where I need help.

Comment: Can't find that class in either JDK7, 8 or 9. are you sure about the package?

Comment: Why do you need to load this particular class, and why like this? Can you show some code where this is used? This must be an X-Y-problem. Nothing that does the same job in the public collection API?

Comment: @Stultuske: It is a package-private class in (at least) JDK8. As an internal JDK class, no one should be using it directly. Defined here (line 613: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/AbstractList.java.html), but gone in later JDK versions.

Answer (score 1):

As @Thilo said in a comment, the class is a private class of the package, it is not part of the interface and therefore should not be used by external user.

That's the reason why you should not produce code that rely on it, because it could be deleted by the package without any notice ( as it seems has happened in JDK9 ).

You should just use the public `LinkedList`, `ArrayList` or similar.

Comment: Apart from opening an issue, as you have already done, there is not much you can do. If the use of the private class is limited, you could replace it with a public list and try to see if it works, while waiting for an answer.

Comment: I tried using ArrayList.  But getting java.lang.NoSuchFieldException.  Wanted to know if there is an equivalent in JDK9 for "java.util.SubList".

Comment: There is really no way to assure, also because it is an implementation-defined thing, so if you, for example, try to execute on a different JVM implementation (Linux has a few) it might give exception on the same version. Maybe you could use the libray in such a way as to never use the wrong code, but that really depends on how you use the library.

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like that:

```
Class c = Class.forName("java.util.List");
```

And then use the `c.subList();`

Comment: This is nonsense; there is no `subList` method in `java.lang.Class`. An instance _of_ a class and the `Class` object _for_ a class are completely different things with completely different types, and types/classes and methods are not even the same category of thing.